# Does it make sense to combine two tables that are one to one if the data is never accessed together?

Tags: sql, performance

I have a question for a particular problem,

Let's say we have some simple platform where a user can create a post which has a title, author, creation date, etc, and a decent amount of content. Content can range anywhere to thousands of characters, probably around 5k max.

Because of the way the UI is designed, only titles will be retrieved, and a user will then click on a title and a page will be loaded with the content. There are two ways I am thinking about going about this:

Firstly, one table in which all the content is stored, each post has it's own row.

Secondly, table A which contains everything except table content and some sort of `post_id` primary key, and a second table, table B which contains only a `post_id` primary key and the `post_content`.

In my mind, It would be efficient to use two tables even though the data is one to one because user content is only singularly loaded, and it shouldn't slow down queries made to the huge post list database(which contains titles, authors, etc).

Am I going about this wrong? Does it not matter since the data won't be selected in the query?

Thank you!

Comment: If you ask for personal opinion, I think you'll get different answers. Some prefer to have two tables and some prefer one. For me personally, immediately on top of my head would prefer two tables. Why? performance wise, I don't really know. I just think it's neat to have two and I *assume* that it might be easier to maintain. But that's just me :)

Comment: @Bug . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged with both MySQL and Postgres. The basic answer is the same for both, but the specifics are different. I know Postgres, so I'll answer for Postgres.

---

Since every post must have content, they go in one table for the reasons of data integrity Bill laid out. The topic is referred to as [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  post_id       bigserial primary key,
  title         text not null,
  author_id     bigint not null references authors(id),
  created_at    timestamp not null default now(),
  content       text not null
);
```

---

[Postgres will optimize `text` and `varchar` for you in a few ways.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-character.html)

> Very long values are also stored in background tables so that they do not interfere with rapid access to shorter column values.

That means Postgres is doing your proposed optimization for you.

> The storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte plus the actual string, which includes the space padding in the case of character. Longer strings have 4 bytes of overhead instead of 1.

`varchar` and `text` will only use as much space as necessary to store the content for each post. Having one very long post does not make the rest of the posts take more space.

> Long strings are compressed by the system automatically, so the physical requirement on disk might be less.

Each post will use even less disk space.

> There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text or character varying should be used instead.

Meaning don't use `char`, only use `varchar` if you need to put a limit on the size, otherwise use `text`. Only put limits on text size if it is dictated by the nature of the data; for example 3-letter country codes would get a `varchar(3)`. Limits such as the maximum length of a post's title are business rules, they can change on a whim, and belong in the application logic.

---

This all means if you don't reference the `content` in a query, it will not affect the performance of your query.

To be performant ***only select the columns you need***. Avoid `select *` when possible. If you only need the title, only select the title.

```
select title
from posts
where author_id = $1
```

That should perform exactly the same with or without a `content` column.

Comment: This was some very helpful insight, thank you! I'll probably just end up using one database for now if the difference is minimal and I'm not handling that much traffic anyways. I'll also use text rather than VARCHAR, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Store the title and content together as columns of the same row.

```
CREATE TABLE Posts (
  post_id       BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  title         VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  author_id     BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  creation_date DATE NOT NULL,
  content       TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Using one table is the only way you can ensure that the columns are not null. That is, if a post exists, it must have content. If you split the content column into another table, the database can't ensure that you must have content for a given post.

Is it possible that it's more efficient to split it into another table? Yes, it's possible, but the difference is small enough that you'd have to have millions of posts and thousands of queries per second before it matters.

Comment: Watch out, `serial` has different sizes in different databases. In MySQL it's `bigint unsigned`. In Postgres it's a range from 1 to 2147483647. `int unsigned` is inappropriate for either.

Comment: Performance Tip:  Don't do `SELECT *` when you don't need to fetch `content`.